# DAX ALLEXCEPT, ALL FUNCTION.. Want to display the overall average in each row

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a measure that contains multiple filters, The Code works perfectly (see column B in image below)

`Service Level = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Centcom'), 'Centcom'[CAMPAIGN] = "Inbound", Centcom[Queue TIme (sec)] <= 1) / [Inbound Calls Handled]`

However, I want to include an ALLEXCEPT FUNCTION in the measure. In the image below, column B shows what I currently have and it works perfectly however can I use the ALLEXCEPT function to achieve column C? In column C, I want all the Team columns to have the same overall average irrespective of the team.

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for (I think oyu have even 2 questions). In column C you want the measure to always who the average of all data, without filter? Then you tell you want to filter by a date but I do not see any date in your example?

Comment: @Aldert my apologies for the confusion, can you ignore the date filter please, the main issue is that I want the overall average for all the rows. Thank you

Comment: You must be kidding me. You are now going to answer your own question based on the insights I gave you?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Average based on no filter at all you can use:

```
SL_All = CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Service Level), ALL('Centcom'))
```

Comment: Thanks Aldert, however, I can not AVERAGE Service Level because its a measure

Answer (score 0):

`Measure = calculate([Sevice level],all(Teams[Team]))`

Also, I modified the Service level measure to

`Service Level= divide(CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Call Log'), 'Call log'[CAMPAIGN] = "Inbound", Call Log[Queue TIme (sec)] <= 1),[Total Inbound Call])`

Hope it works for you